# No language switcher

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

After (as I suppose) updating my Ubuntu 12.04 is refuses to change keyboard layout and only allows me to type in english. It even doesn't show language bar at the top. What is the way to solve that problem?

*Here are screens of 'Keyboard layout' and 'Language support' from my 'System settings'*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just noticed that in log-in screen input language switcher works properly

Answer (score 0):

In the "Language Support" dialog, drag your prefered language above "English". "English" must be last in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the English entry in Keyboard Layout and in Language Support drag the options to put your preferred languages in order, so that Russian will be first and English last in the list, then click the button Apply System-Wide.

Comment: I removed English, but there's still no language indicator at the top, and I can type only in english

Comment: I know this is somewhat dumb, but have you tried to update your system(`sudo apt-get upgrade`)? And does the command `sudo apt-get update` returns any errors?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, no errors :(

Answer (score 0):

In the keyboard Layout window press the Options botton. In the displayed options around the middle there is a section "Key(s) to change layout" Take a look at it and change it to your liking.